# Login-Admin problems in PHP (Undefined index: myusername in...)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to build a login connection on my website project. I have a few errors and don't know how to resolve them. I've tried watching some tutorials..

Can you give me a little help, please?

**My Code:**

```
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 

**$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];** 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    $_SESSION['myusername']= $myusername;
    $_SESSION['mypassword']= $mypassword; 
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
```

**Getting these errors:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: myusername in C:\xampp\htdocs\gaming\admin\admin_login.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: mypassword in C:\xampp\htdocs\gaming\admin\admin_login.php on line 17
```

Comment: are you 'post'ing the username and password?

Comment: it simply means that there is no posted data that means `$_POST` have no values.

Comment: I have a form, with a myusername&mypassword input-text, login... When i press login, it calls that big code, with db connection.

Comment: your form code please?

Comment: and if any type of javascript or jquery code is used then that also show.

Comment: Up to my form code, i take a JavaScript. I use JS and Ajax, for no reloading pages.

Comment: <script src="js/admin.js"/>

  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" id="admin_login">
       <strong>ADMIN LOGIN</strong>
      
       <input type="text" name="myusername">
        <input type="text" name="mypassword">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        
     <div id="result"></div>

Comment: MY JS CODE
$(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "admin/admin_login.php",
     data: $("#admin_login").serialize(),
     success: function(data){
      $('#result').html(data);
      }
     });
    });
})

Comment: I resolved my errors with: $myusername = isset($_POST['myusername']) ? $_POST['myusername'] : '';
$mypassword = isset($_POST['mypassword']) ? $_POST['mypassword'] : '';

Comment: But still, if i put my USERNAME and PASSWORD, it goes on my echo: "Wrong Username or Password", and it not connect, even if i have my login.php file.